# Application crash (Segmentation fault: 11) when turning on voice over

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, crash

I am seeing a strange crash in my app with message "Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11". This happens every time I launch my app and then go to a navigation view stack and then go to device settings and turn on the voice over and then when I come back to my app and go back to previous view controller - it crashes.

Interestingly, crash does not happen when I do not turn on the voice over and come back to the app.

Any clue?

I see this in the crash log:

```
[UITableViewRowData heightForAutohidingTableHeaderView]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Below is what I see after enabling NSZombie:

[image]

Comment: Is this while debugging through Xcode?

Comment: It happens both with and without XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to iOS 7 bug. Found a workaround for this which worked. Added the below dealloc method and it worked fine.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.tableView.editing = NO;
    self.tableView.delegate = nil;
}
```